# Should I use the conditional continuous or simple?

Tags: subjunctives, politeness

Should I say:

> If I was a detective, **I would ask**

or

> If I was a detective, **I would be asking**

Is the second one ("be asking") only a form to stress politeness?

Comment: If I were a detective...

Answer (score 1):

Which you *should* say depends on the context.

No, the second form is not only a form to stress politeness. It doesn't really seem more polite at all. It's a different tense, and should be used in a different situation.

**If I was a detective, I would ask**

This is the [simple conditional](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uses_of_English_verb_forms#Simple_conditional) tense. It can be used when you're referring to a question you would ask now, or in a hypothetical situation (including the future).

Example Question:

> What would you ask someone after they were robbed?

Example Answer:

> If I was a detective, I would ask them if they saw the thief's face.

**I would be asking**

This is the [conditional progressive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uses_of_English_verb_forms#Conditional_progressive) tense. It can be used when you're referring to a question you would be asking right now.

Example Question:

> Why are you asking? Are you a detective?

Example Answer:

> If I was a detective, I would be asking about the thief.